# Inquire deliveries created from Postmates App/website

Tags: postmates

From POS system point of view, how do I list Postmates deliveries which were CREATED from Postmates app or Postmates website? Via Postmates documentation, it seems like I can only [list deliveries](https://postmates.com/developer/docs/#resources__delivery__list-deliveries) which I [created](https://postmates.com/developer/docs/#resources__delivery__create-delivery) myself, but I can't list deliveries which customers created directly from Postmates website/app.

I'm trying to write application for POS system which polls for deliveries from Postmates and print directly into kitchen printer.